# Is there a way to connect Snowflake with R using OAuth?

Tags: r, oauth, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We've got a Snowflake database which we access through OAuth (we also have IDs and passwords just in case), and I've got a number of R scripts (using the ODBC & DBI libraries) that query and update tables there. Is there a way to use OAuth to make the connection, instead of my ID and password? Not sure how useful a code sample is, but here's a very simple one that runs, but it requires manually inputting a password each time:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

sfConn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Snowflake", uid = "USERNAME",
                         warehouse = "WH",
                         database = "DB",
                         schema = "SCHEMA",
                         pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword()
                         )



q1 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(sfConn, '
  select Top 100 *
  from SOME_TABLE
')

DBI::dbDisconnect(sfConn)
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: When you say that you access your snowflake database through Oauth, what does that mean? Are you accessing this database through tableau or something?

Comment: Yes, it's mostly Tableau but we also get in through a web portal (also using Oauth) and make queries/updates there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following parameter to connect to SF through OAuth:

```
sfConn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Snowflake", 
                     uid = "USERNAME"
                     authenticator="OAUTH",
                     token = "access_token",
                     warehouse = "WH",
                     database = "DB",
                     schema = "SCHEMA"
                     )
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and got this error message:
"Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 28000: Invalid OAuth access token."

Do you know if there are any other options for the token field?

Comment: The error implies that the token is missing some values that is necessary to establish the connection with Snowflake. Run the following command on Snowflake as "accountadmin" to verify the token :select SYSTEM$VERIFY_EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN ('<token generated>');    . If this shows success, then the token generated is correct and can be used for connecting to any application using OAuth means. 
Replace "access_token" with the actual token value and test with a token that shows "passed" from SF with the above test.

Comment: Thanks! I think at this point it's a question for the admin. I appreciate the help, it got me partway there.